# How do i know how long the application is running in background in android?

Tags: android, background

I want to calculate how long other application (ex:- Music) is running in background in my application. I have seen this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133262/how-to-know-for-how-much-long-the-application-is-running-in-android) did not get any useful info for my expectation.

I think there will be some API in android to calculate this, because "Spare parts" application is doing same job as i am expecting.

Comment: Have you looked at the source for spare parts?  Though that may just be brining up something in the settings menu rather than display it itself.  The /proc/pid##/stat cpu usage counters seem readable for a foreign android process, but would only reflect the amount of time the current process of that application has been running, not the total time for all processes which might have hosted that app (and it's cpu usage time, not clock time)

Comment: Thanks a lot i was not aware of this info.

Answer (score 1):

See the below link you may find some use full information [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903650/time-that-an-application-is-running)

or you may refer the link for spareParts [spareParts](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-development/com/android/spare_parts/SpareParts.java.htm)