# Determine how long an Android application (not mine) is visible

Tags: android, time, visible

I'm writing an application that will need to know how long any given application is visible to the user.

Is there any system-wide event that my service could receive when an application is opened and when it is no longer visible to the user (onStop())? Or do I have to resort to periodically polling the ActivityManager?

The applications Tasker(http://tasker.dinglisch.net) seems to be able to detect when any given application is visible/invisible. Do they simply poll ActivityManager, or is there some other way of going about this?

Ref:

[Time that an application is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903650/time-that-an-application-is-running) 
[How to know for how much long the application is running in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133262/how-to-know-for-how-much-long-the-application-is-running-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

You can detect whether your app is visible or not the following way:

In all your your Activity, set:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

VisibilityManager.setIsVisible(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
VisibilityManager.setIsVisible(false);

super.onPause();
}
```

(this may lead you to define a superclass to all your activities that would implement this behaviour)

Then create a VisibilityManager (this one is very basic, you may need something more advanced):

```
public class VisibilityManager {
private boolean mIsVisible = false;

public void setIsVisible(boolean visible) { 
     mIsVisible = visible; 
}

public boolean getIsVisible() {
     return mIsVisible;
}
}
```

And then, in your timer thread, when the countdown reached zero you can kill the application:

```
if (VisibilityManager.getIsVisible()) {
finish();
}
else {
showNotification();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if I'm monitoring my own application. However, I need to be able to determine the run time of OTHER applications that aren't mine. I'm currently looking at the SpareParts source code to see how they do it.